# Postgresql 9.5 on ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

im try install postgresql on ubuntu using this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dSqosCc_KLA
And im stop on step when print comand `psql` 4:54 seconds video

> psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
>           Is the server running locally and accepting
>           connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue, I had that too. Try to reinstall postgresql with a version number. Remove your postgres and reinstall it. For example:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.5
```

An other fix would be to create a softlink for example:

```
ln -s /tmp/pgsql.5432 /var/run/postgresql/pgsql.5432
```

I would suggest you to reinstall postgresql like I said in point 1.

Note: default port of postgresql is 5432

Comment: im run sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.5
But its not solve problem

Comment: Did you try to create a softlink?